# Theme Functions run a function upon activation or preview

Tags: plugins, php, theme-development

My theme currently has the following line in the function.php file:
 `if ( $_GET['activated'] == 'true'  || $_GET['preview'] == 1 )`  If this statement is true the code runs a function.

I am getting a php error that says Notice: Undefined index: activated in and Notice: Undefined index: preview in.

I am sure in wordrpess there is another way to do this "if statement" to prevent the  Undefined index: error I am getting.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Here is the full code:

```
//ADD OPTION PAGE
add_action('admin_menu', 'ddthemes_admin');

//UPON ACTIVATION OR PREVIEWED
if ( $_GET['activated'] == 'true'  || $_GET['preview'] == 1 ) {
    ddthemes_setup();
}

function ddthemes_admin() {
    /* PROCESS OPTION SAVING HERE */
    if ( 'save' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {
        if ( $_REQUEST['savetype'] == 'header' ) {
            update_option( 'ddthemes_header', $_REQUEST['ddthemes_header']);
        }
    }
    
    /* SHOW THEME CUSTOMIZE PAGE HERE */
    add_theme_page(__('Logo Options'), __('Logo Options'), 'edit_themes', basename(__FILE__), 'ddthemes_headeropt_page');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if ( isset($_GET['activated']) && $_GET['activated'] == 'true' || isset($_GET['preview']) && $_GET['preview'] == 1 )
```

instead of

```
if ( $_GET['activated'] == 'true' || $_GET['preview'] == 1 )
```

**Edit:**

You should wrap the if-sentence in the functions.php file into a function and a relevant hook. Here is an example using the `after_theme_setup` hook:

```
add_action('after_theme_setup','my_theme_setup');
function my_theme_setup(){
    if ( isset($_GET['activated']) && $_GET['activated'] == 'true' || isset($_GET['preview']) && $_GET['preview'] == 1 ){
        ddthemes_setup();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank your for the reply.  I used your code and got this error `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home3/an/public_html/wp-content/themes/tipztheme/functions.php:1) in /home3/answerun/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 876`  I updated the full code above, perhaps that is causing the error with isset.  Any ideas?

Comment: the if-code you are using is not within a function and most likely `ddthemes_setup()` is printing out some stuff. you should consider to hook it into `init` or some relevant hook.

Comment: it looks like the hook `after_setup_theme` could be relevant - I updated the code example above.

Comment: thank you so much.  That worked to solve the issue.  One minor error in your code `{` at opening of the if statement.  Thank you again!

Comment: ok great, I updated the code with the missing { - thanks